# Correct way of using a confirm dialog Box before submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

what is the correct way of using the confirm dialog box before the submit form? I see two problem in my implementation, but can´t find solution.
1)I show a dialog box while submitting. I am using a global variable "val" in ShowConfirmation, this is not visible outside the ShowConfirmation function. If I use debugger, "val" is undefined in ".Submit" function.
2)Because i have "e.preventDefault" the form is not submitted. Forcing "submit" in function ShowConfirmation does not submit the form.

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="CONFIRM" onclick="Confirm())">
<Script>
var val;
$("#form").submit(function(e)
{
  // confirmation popup
  e.preventDefault();

  if (val==true)
  {
  // Do something
  }

})

ShowConfirmation(val) {
var r = confirm("Press a button");
if (r == true) {
  console.log("you pressed ok");
  .....
  val=true;
  $("#form").submit();
}
else {
  console.log("you pressed cancel");
  }
}
Confirm() {
...
...
ShowConfirmation(val);
}
</Script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following code helps:

```js
$("#form").submit(function()
{

  if (confirm("Press a button"))
  {
     // Do something
     console.log("you pressed ok");
     $(this).off("submit").submit();
  }
  else {
     console.log("you pressed cancel");
  }
  return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you listen to the submit and then call it back (using $(this).submit()) you will join an endless loop which can be stopped just by not pressing ok on the confirm box.

Instead of all your functions, the situation is actually very easy.

HTML (Example):

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#form').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    confirm("Are you sure?") ? $(this).submit() : alert("ok..");
});
```

Instead of using variables and stuff like that, we just want to check if the user confirmed or not, therefore we are using the comfortable ternary operator:

```
confirm("Are you sure?") ? $(this).submit() : alert("ok..");
```

if the user confirms, it will submit the form, else it will alert ok. If you have two functions, just declare them **correctly**, you are missing the **function** before your function names.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1jkyuez8/1/

Comment: I am using my own custom confirm dialog which is following some css and buttons, "yes" and "no". Adding $(this).submit(); to button YES does not trigger the submit action. If I use simple confirm("Are you sure")? $(this).submit() : alert("ok.."), then it work fine.

Comment: Can you please post your entire code then? What are you returning from your "yes" and "no"?